# CSS positioning div inside other div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

I have a webpage that looks a bit like in the following plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/UyM3DDrH9Y5P8jGTfLp4?p=preview

In short: I have a header and a subheader.
On one of the pages, I have a list (in column way) on which I can select on any item. After selecting, the form on the right should fill up with the correct info, so I can change it.

Now my question is related to positioning. Since the list goes way further than the page, there is a page scroll.

What I want is that the form will scroll down together with it. So The user doesn't have to go up the page after selecting any item.
Is there a way to make it fixed (without JQuery) according to it's upper div? I don't want to make it fixed according to the page, since it's not fixed how high the top of the page will be.

- It would be nice if the form would, while scrolling, fill up the space of the navigation bar(s) first too. So there won't be any gap on top of the page. (while scrolling)

I don't know if my question is any clear.

So my code (in short) looks kinda like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    // Here will be navbar items
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
       // Here the list will be (list-group) 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
        <form>
            //This form represents edit fields for the items in the list
            // I want this form to be on top of page while scrolling down the list.
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Kind regards

Comment: Is `position:sticky` what you need?

Comment: Is there a reason you're against using JS or JQuery? It sounds like you want sticky positioning, which does exist in CSS `position: sticky;`but browser support is limited. There are multiple JS/JQuery solutions available.

Comment: Sticky is something I can't really use, cause it needs to be working on all browsers used inside the company, and the IE version is not up to date yet it seems. I'm not really against using JS or JQuery, but I'm hoping there is a simple CSS solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But if I have, I think this is the solution your seeking: (It needs some extra styling)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
    #formright {
      position:fixed;
      top:1;
      right:0;
      width:600px;
    }
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }
      @media (max-width: 979px) {

        /* Remove any padding from the body */
        body {
          padding-top: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul  class="nav nav-tabs navmargin">
        <li  class="subnav active" ><a>Zenders</a></li>
        <li  class="subnav"><a>Bronnen</a></li>
        <li  class="subnav"><a>Programma's</a></li>
        <li  class="subnav"><a>Gebruikers</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <admin-channels _nghost-c4="">
      <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group">
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
          <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="list-group-item" data-id="1">VTM</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="formright">
      <div  class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
        <form  novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <div  class="form-group">
            <label  class="control-label col-md-3" for="name">Naam</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Vul naam in..." required="" type="text" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="name" ng-reflect-model="VIER">
            </div>
           </div>

          <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-group">
            <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="control-label col-md-3" for="papercuts">Gebruiken</label>
            <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-9">
                <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="showChannel" name="showChannel" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="showChannel" ng-reflect-model="true">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-group">
            <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%" type="submit">Opslaan</button>
                <button _ngcontent-c4="" canceltext="Nee" class="btn btn-danger" confirmtext="Ja" message="Bent u zeker?" mwlconfirmationpopover="" placement="top" style="width: 100%" title="Verwijderen zender" type="button" ng-reflect-title="Verwijderen zender" ng-reflect-message="Bent u zeker?" ng-reflect-confirm-text="Ja" ng-reflect-cancel-text="Nee" ng-reflect-placement="top">Verwijderen</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </admin-channels>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Didn't really do the trick for now (since I still have the white space while scrolling). But it did help me figuring out to using "position: fixed" and "float:right" on the "div col-sm..." to make it fixed on the same size. It's a start. Thanks a lot already ! :-)